# Visual Studio 2017 not showing API request traces

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Earlier I had a feature that was showing me the successful API requests over a specific controller, now this feature is gone, do you know which one it could be?

[image]

I'm not sure if it's a Resharper feature...

How I can enable it again?

EDIT: I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise

Comment: What was the attribute name?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? I believe that the tracing data is only available in the Enterprise edition

Comment: It wasn't an attribute name, it was like integrated with visual studio, even on each property line of a class, I had a text showing the author of the code from the VCS, and how many modifications it had.

Comment: Edited! I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

After digging deeper, I finally found it, the name of the feature is CodeLens.

How to enable it: [How to enable CodeLens for Visual Studio 2017 Community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991430/how-to-enable-codelens-for-visual-studio-2017-community)